How do I set a website's name that appears above the URL on Google search?
When searching for Stackoverflow on Google different things are displayed on the result:


"Stack Overflow"
"https://stackoverflow.com" > The url
"Stack Overflow - Where developers Learn, Share & Build" > The page title

I'm confused on how to change the first "Stack Overflow" text.
I initially thought it was the Open Graph property, but that doesn't seem to always match what's in that text.
